# facebook api - get email with <fb:>

Tags: php, html, facebook

I have for facebook:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title>head</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>head</h1>
  <p><fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button></p>
  <p><fb:like></fb:like></p>

  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({appId: '111111111111', status: true, cookie: true,
               xfbml: true});
    };
    (function() {
      var e = document.createElement('script');
      e.type = 'text/javascript';
      e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
      e.async = true;
      document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

what i must edit in this that get email address? i must use library facebook.php and login and logout with variables $loginUrl and $logoutUrl?
I would like use

```
<p><fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button></p>
```

Comment: Why not just use the Facebook JavaScript SDK which you're already including in your page?

Answer (score 0):

There is no known way of getting email through xfbml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" scope="email"></fb:login-button>
```